# Hidden column of grid in EXT JS 5.0 when using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, extjs

I has question about ExtJs 5.0 when intergrated with bootstrap.
I create gridPanel

```
var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

        plugins : [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', 
        {
            clicksToEdit : 2
        })],
        columnLines: true,  
        // Add store 
        store:'ABC.store.StudentStore',
        columns:[
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                header : 'Id',
                dataIndex:'id',
                hidden : false,
                width : 35,
                cls:'hidden-xs hidden-sm',
                hideable: false
            }, 
            {
                header : 'First Name',
                xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                dataIndex:'fName',
                flex : 1,
                field : 
                {
                    xtype: 'numberfield'
                }
            }, 
            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                header : 'Middle Name',
                dataIndex:'mName',
                flex : 1,
                editor : 
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    selectOnFocus: true,
                    allowBlank : true
                }
            }
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    }

    );
```

in `StudentStore`, I add some data for grid.
I set class `hidden-xs hidden-sm` of bootstrap for column `Id`.

Question is: When I re-size browser for small or extra-small, only header `Id` is disappear, but column `Id` is not disappear. How to disappear column Id when re-size browser for small or extra-small.
Please help me in this case.

Comment: Since you are using ExtJS5 you could make the grid responsive.  [Check out this stack question for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995667/using-responsive-plugin-in-extjs-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `responsive` plugin in extjs5 to adjust the columns based on the `width`.

Add `responsive` to your plugins array:

```
plugins: ['responsive'],
```

define a `config` for the method to change the `columns`:

```
config: {
                columnLayout: 'large'
            },
```

Add a `setter` for this property:

```
updateColumnLayout: function(size) {
                switch (size) {
                case 'small':
                        if(!this.columns[0].setVisible)
                            this.columns[0].hidden = true;
                        else
                            this.columns[0].setVisible(false);
                    break;
                case 'medium':
                        if(!this.columns[0].setVisible)
                            this.columns[0].hidden = false;
                        else
                            this.columns[0].setVisible(true);
                    break;
                case 'large':
                    break;
                }
            },
```

Define in the `responsiveConfig` the `size` to pass through to our setter:

```
responsiveConfig: {
                'width <= 600': {
                    columnLayout: 'small'
                },
                'width > 600': {
                    columnLayout: 'medium'
                },
                'width >= 1600': {
                    columnLayout: 'medium'
                }
            },
```

Here is a [fiddle demonstrating the working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mk3).

I'm calling `small` for `width`'s under `600` and `medium` for everything above.  You can adjust these parameters to your needs.

Comment: Can't using pure bootstrap for disappear column ?